# Dom functions, inserting HTML to the dom replacing all content

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I find the `table` functionality of Javascript very cool, but I ran across this problem where I cannot replace the content of an element (`div`) by the `table` I created using

```
var mytable = document.createElement('table');
...
...
foo.innerHTML = myTable;
```

but I can `appendChild` to `foo` like so

```
foo.appendChild(myTable);
```

The problem is that it only appends, I wanted to replace the html of foo? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Well you could always do this:

```
foo.innerHTML = "";
foo.appendChild(myTable);
```

Answer (score 2):

Before calling append, do:

```
foo.innerHTML = '';
```

to clear the contents of foo.